# how to specify welcome-file-list in WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup()

Tags: spring, web.xml, welcome-file, programmatic-config

Currently I have a web application where we are using web.xml to configure the application. The web.xml has welcome-file-list.

```
<web-app>  
   ...
   <welcome-file-list>  
     <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>  
   </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

We are planning to use spring framework and use java class for application configuration.

```
class MyApplication extends WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartUp(ServletContext context){
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I specify welcome-file-list in this java class?

Comment: I don't believe you can.

Answer (score 20):

While developing Spring MVC application with pure Java Based Configuration, we can set the home page by making our application configuration class extending the [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) class and override the [addViewControllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addViewControllers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry-) method where we can set the default home page as described below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp.controllers" })
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
  }

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
  }

}
```

It returns `home.jsp` view which can be served as home page. No need to create a custom controller logic to return the home page view.

The JavaDoc for [addViewControllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addViewControllers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry-) method says -

> Configure simple automated controllers pre-configured with the
>   response status code and/or a view to render the response body. This
>   is useful in cases where there is no need for custom controller logic
>   -- e.g. render a home page, perform simple site URL redirects, return a 404 status with HTML content, a 204 with no content, and more.

**2nd way** - For static HTML file home page we can use the code below in our configuration class. It will return `index.html` as a home page -

```
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
```

**3rd way** - The request mapping "/" below will also return `home` view which can be served as a home page for an app. But the above ways are recommended.

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/" })
    public String homePage() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

## You can't

As specified in [Java Doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

> **`public interface WebApplicationInitializer`**
>
> `Interface` to be implemented
>   in Servlet 3.0+ environments in order to configure the ServletContext
>   programmatically -- as opposed to (or possibly in conjunction with)
>   the traditional web.xml-based approach.

but you still need minimal configuration in web.xml , such as for

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Although this answer is correct (you cannot :) ). You might want to add that this isn't actually related to Spring but the fact that isn't implemented in the ``ServletContext` i.e. java based configuration approach for servlet containers. Even when not using Spring and using a plain `ServletContainerInitializer` it will not be possible, at least not in a servlet container agnostic way.

Answer (score 5):

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.springapp.mvc")
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pages/");
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}
...
}
```

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me...

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}
```