# How to set the welcome-file when developing spring mvc application with pure Java based configuration and no web.xml?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, welcome-file

I am developing a web application using Spring MVC with pure Java based and no web.xml configuration. I did code the class  below to load the beans and set the url pattern. How can I set the the welcome-file?

```
public class MyAppWebAppIntializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appCtx.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appCtx));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972676/how-to-specify-welcome-file-list-in-webapplicationinitializer-onstartup

Comment: How about using a controller with "/" as request mapping and return the view you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cpd214. I actually did the same thing and it did work.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972676/how-to-specify-welcome-file-list-in-webapplicationinitializer-onstartup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While developing Spring MVC application with pure Java Based Configuration,  we can set the home page by making our application configuration class extending the [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) class and override the  [addViewControllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addViewControllers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry-) method where we can set the default home page as described below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myapp.controllers" })
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
  }

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
  }

}
```

It returns `home.jsp` view which can serve as a home page. No need to create a custom controller logic to return the home page view.

The JavaDoc for [addViewControllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addViewControllers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry-) method says -

> Configure simple automated controllers pre-configured with the
>   response status code and/or a view to render the response body. This
>   is useful in cases where there is no need for custom controller logic
>   -- e.g. render a home page, perform simple site URL redirects, return a 404 status with HTML content, a 204 with no content, and more.

***2nd way*** -  For static HTML file home page we can use the code below in our configuration class -

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
```

***3rd way -*** 
The request mapping "/" below will also return home.jsp which can be served as a home page for an app. But the above process is recommended.

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/" })
    public String homePage() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```