# Spring boot index page not mapped to / in Tomcat deployment

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

Yet another issue with deploying Spring Boot WAR to Tomcat... I have read the dozen of similar questions but have not found any fix for my issue.

I have a Spring Boot web app which is working fine when using the embedded tomcat web server (I can reach the index.html page using localhost:8080).
However when I deploy the WAR to Tomcat (the war is called ROOT.war so am I deploying the app at Tomcat's root), localhost:8080 returns 404. I need to call localhost:8080/index.html to get an answer. I just cannot figure out why!

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
            <executions>
                ...
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

I have one `@RestController` which does not override "/", and that's it.
In the generated WAR, the index.html is located at the top level (so same level as WEB-INF).
I also noticed that when Tomcat starts the web app, it prints:

```
INFO ServletWebServerApplicationContext ServletWebServerApplicationContext.prepareWebApplicationContext(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:292) [main] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1674 ms
INFO WelcomePageHandlerMapping WelcomePageHandlerMapping.<init>(WelcomePageHandlerMapping.java:53) [main] Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]
```

I find the second line strange: it looks like Spring Boot is choosing to default back to a `WelcomePageHandlerMapping` instead of using the expected spring boot context. No idea where that comes from.

Maybe another indication: it does not print

```
Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

while this is printed when I start the app using the embedded Tomcat web server. But maybe it is fine if it is not there.

Tomcat version: 9.0.65
Tomcat config: default config: did not change anything there since installation.

Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30972676/592355 , or just adding/fixing web.xml

Comment: @xerx593 I do have the setting you pasted in my Tomcat install web.xml file, but I do not have any web.xml file in my app. Isn't what SpringBootServletInitializer is supposed to do: configuring the web server context?

Comment: In particular, my appication.properties file does NOT contain any spring related config som server.servlet.context-path or spring.mvc.servlet.path, and I do not want to recourse to a web.xml file as the point of using Spring Boot is precisely to not need one.

Comment: @xerx593, I did follow the 3rd way (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995679/4965515) and it worked, but it should not be needed to add a Controller to redirect from / to /index.html because of the default welcome-file mechanism defined in Tomcat's web.xml file. But thanks for the link, it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I could reproduce!

With:

- `Dockerfile`:

  ```dockerfile
  FROM tomcat:9.0.69-jre17-temurin-jammy
  ARG WAR_FILE=target/ROOT.war
  RUN addgroup --system tomcat \
     && adduser --system --ingroup tomcat tomcat \
     && chown -Rfh tomcat:tomcat $CATALINA_HOME
  USER tomcat:tomcat
  COPY ${WAR_FILE} $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/
  CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
  ```
- `pom.xml`:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <!-- max spring boot version for tomcat 9 (servlet-api): -->
      <version>2.7.6</version> 
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
     </parent>
     <groupId>com.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>traditional</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>war</packaging>
     <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
     <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
      <!-- latest tomcat9 version, property controls spring dependency management: -->
      <tomcat.version>9.0.69</tomcat.version> 
     </properties>
     <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <build>
      <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
      <!-- no spring-boot plugin!(?) -->
     </build>
  </project>
  ```
- App/Entry:

  ```java
  package com.example.traditional;

  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
  import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

  @SpringBootApplication
  public class TraditionalApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(TraditionalApplication.class, args);
     }
     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
      return builder.sources(TraditionalApplication.class);
     }
  }
  ```
- (Some `/custom` controller, (mockMvc) tests)
- and a "static `index.html`" in **`src/main/webapp`** (maven war default):

  ```html
  <html>
     <body>
       <h1>Hello</h1>
       Hello World!
     </body>
  </html>
  ```
- the (embedded tomcat) test succeeds:

  ```java
  @WebMvcTest
  public class WebTest {

     @Autowired
     MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Test
     void testRoot() throws Exception {
      mockMvc
         .perform(
            get("/")
         ).andExpectAll(
            status().isOk(),
            forwardedUrl("index.html")
         );
     } // ...
  }
  ```
- but after:

  - `mvn clean install \`
  - `&& docker build -t my/tomcat9-app . \`
  - `&& docker run -p 8080:8080 my/tomcat9-app`,
- we get:

  - `404` (tomcat error page) from `http://localhost:8080`
  - (`http://localhost:8080/index.html`, `http://localhost:8080/custom` work as expected ;(#

#### Simplest Solution

Move `index.html` from `src/main/webapp` to **`src/main/resources/static`** ! (stop running container, repeat `mvn clean install && docker build ... && docker run`);p #

Comment: I tried moving my html files til src/main/resources/static, but when doing so they appear in WEB-INF/classes/static in the WAR, and running the app in Tomcat doesn't work (error 404). Is there something to change in the POM config?

Comment: 404 (in that case) means; the (spring boot) app didn't load normally... Do you see "spring boot banner"/some spring log messages (out/logs) on tomcat start?

Comment: Indeed there was an issue with Tomcat. Now everything works without requiring the ugly "home controller hack". Thanks a lot fr the help :)

Comment: Cool, welcome, thx & was a pleasure to me! .. unfortunately the "explanation" is more complex than the "recommenation" ! (Spring (boot) static resource handling + external container...)